# A comparison between "story" and "floor"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

According to the nuance between a floor and a story (AmE) what sentence would be correct when you're going to ask someone about the number of floors/stories of a building?

> - How many floors does that building have?
> - How many stories high is that building?

I know that using the words "story" and "floor" are different, but whereas I have read so many pages and a similar page on stackexchange, I found out that the usage of these two words are different; so when I search on google I bump into many webpages containing both constructions above snd this is why I cannot make sure which one would be correct to be said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It depends on the situation...

**When you're talking about windows,** it might be more acceptable to say:

> It's a second-story window!

than:

> It's a second-floor window!

, though both, as you can see, still work fine.

**When you're talking about location,** you generally say "floor" as in,

> I live on the fourth floor.

instead of

> I live on the fourth story.

In this case, *floor* is probably the more applicable term.

*Please leave a comment if you want me to include more situations!*

Comment: I've seen cases where an owner of a building will give its height in "standard" stories, even if it doesn't have that many floors. For instance, if there are 50 floors, and they're 10% higher than the floors in most buildings, then the building might be claimed to be 55 stories high. This is hardly a universally accepted practice, however.

Comment: Thank you @invent palooza; so you mean both of my senences are correct, while whereas it's about "building/an object", the "story" construction works better, although the "floor" version can be said in natural English too; right?

Comment: @A-friend That's exactly right!